# How/where do I publish a 50-page-long writeup?

Tags: publications, journals, conference, writing

I've written this document developing a new theoretical model, with many definitions, some examples (with diagrams), and some fundamental uses of this model which are closely intertwined with its definition (specifically, without them it is not clear why it's interesting at all). It does not present nor discuss experimental results.

So, this thing is shaping up to take somewhere between 45-50 pages (still working on a few parts of it). Granted, that's in 1-column mode and in the default font size of the article document class, and there are generously-sized diagrams, a TOC, references and an index - but still, pretty long. I don't think that a reasonable 10-12 page conference paper can be cut out of it: Either it would have no grounding and be based on hand-waving; or it would be bits-and-pieces all over the place; or it would be a long series of definitions which doesn't go somewhere very interesting. On the other hand, this is not book-length material.

My question is: How / in what kind of venue could I try to get this thing published?

Notes:

- I'm in applied computer science, even if the document is somewhat theoretical/reflective.
- I'm open to outside-the-box suggestions

Comment: You can always publish a shortened version in a journal (which generally have higher page allowances) and link to the full version on ArXiv, but that is probably not the preferred method for you.

Comment: @malexmave: I wonder if it's not the _only_ method though.

Comment: Can some material be moved to an appendix? I am in Econ and many theory papers include several appendixes, including proofs for minor results etc.

Comment: A book chapter in LNCS series is a possibility?

Comment: @Memming: I'd be the only chapter in the book (un)fortunately; but - if you can write a couple of paragraphs that could be an answer for people in generally.

Comment: @Dawn: That might work for 20-page writeup, not 50.

Comment: There are journals in computer science that publish long papers. [Logical methods in computer science](https://lmcs.episciences.org/) is an example, although perhaps it is not the right venue for your current paper. However, I think it is likely there are journals in your specialty that would work.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Are you sure that long-paper journals exist in many/most subfields of Computer Science? If you are, perhaps you could make this comment into an answer, with some examples.

Comment: Are you sure that 50 pages is too long for an applied CS journal paper? I'm in pure math and have several papers that are 50-70 pages long, and that's not too unusual in many areas of math.

Comment: Your paper has an _index_? Really?

Comment: @DanRomik: 1. It's not really a "paper". If I told I wrote a booklet you wouldn't be surprised. 2. My writeup defines multiple Foos, scattered in different places. So I have an Index of Foos.

Answer (score 1):

The options are really to either find a place that will publish in the format that it is or to figure out how to break it up.

The first thing I would do is try and get an accurate estimate of the length. A 50 page document with the standard LaTeX font and margins that includes a TOC, index and big diagrams may not actually be too long for a lot of journals. Depending on the complexity of the article, you can try creating a "preprint" to get a pretty good approximation of length. A 20 page article can probably be made to stay under the maximum length requirements of many journals. Getting a 40 page article to work will likely not be possible.

In terms of breaking it up, you need to figure out how to chunk the work.

> Either it would have no grounding and be based on hand-waving; or it would be bits-and-pieces all over the place; or it would be a long series of definitions which doesn't go somewhere very interesting.

Trying to publish *bits-and-pieces all over the place* is going to be painful. Most reviewers want some sort of cohesive story. The other two options sound like dividing the work into two chunks. The first chunk seems like something you could publish in a good journal if somehow the theoretical grounding was published.

The second chunk seems boring that no *good* journal is going to want to publish. I see three approaches to getting it published. The first is to publish the second chunk as a stand alone item. Depending on your field you might be able to publish it as a methods article or in a methods journal. You could also target a low impact journal/conference that is targeting work that is slightly better than pay-to-publish quality and doesn't really care if things are *interesting*. Finally, you could use something like ArXiv (or whatever your field uses) to *self publish* the work.

The second option is to publish the second chunk as supplemental material in a journal that allows that. Here is an example of what [APS supplemental material](https://journals.aps.org/authors/supplemental-materials-journals) can include.

The final option, and probably the most difficult, is to find a journal that allows big appendices.

Comment: Does CS regularly do books with chapters and/or monographs?  50 pages in the humanities is a perfect fit for a chapter in a book.  Or alternatively, could it perhaps be beefed up and published as a short-ish monograph?